# Parsing Raw Emails from Amazon SES in Java

Tags: java, email, amazon-web-services, jakarta-mail

**Here is the problem I'm facing:**

1. I'm receiving a raw email from Amazon SES into an S3 bucket, triggering a Lambda function.
2. The function reads the data (raw email) from the bucket using:

   S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(srcBucket, srcKey));
3. The raw email is then converted to an InputStream and the Java Mail (javax.mail) MimeMessage object is created:

   MimeMessage mimeMessageObj = new MimeMessage(newSession, inputStreamObj);

**The question is:**
How do you parse out all the information from the message (inlcuding attachments).

MimeMessage seems to have specialized methods for that (getSubject, etc), but they return nulls. Is there a special parsing necessary before those fields are populated? I found a lot of examples of creating email messages using those special methods directly, but reversing the process to read raw email feed does not seem to work properly. Is manual parsing the only option? That would be very tedious and error prone I assume.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the `MimeMessageParser` from the `org.apache.commons.mail.util` package.

Your code should then look like this:

```
MimeMessage mimeMessageObj = new MimeMessage(newSession, inputStreamObj);
MimeMessageParser mimeParser = new MimeMessageParser(mimeMessageObj);

try {
    mimeParser.parse();
    List<javax.mail.Address> to = mimeParser.getTo();
    String from = mimeParser.getFrom();
    String subject = mimeParser.getSubject();
    String bodyPlain = mimeParser.getPlainContent();
    String bodyHtml = mimeParser.getHtmlContent();
    long timestamp = mime.getSentDate().getTime();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the maven dependency you will need:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting nulls, then the message isn't really a MIME format message.  Make sure it is, and that there's no blank lines at the beginning of the message.